# How to concatenate/merge rows with data and null values in Visual Insight/ Microstrategy

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, microstrategy

In a  Visual Insight I wonder if there is a way to generate only one celd when I have null values and data in the same column. Just like in the  attached image. (This result set is based on a query that I can not modified).

Regards,  [image]

Answer (score 1):

No you can't achieve this directly I guess, because each cell has mapping to its other columns irrespective of what value it holds.

Since you have specified that you can't modify the SQL. You can create a derived attribute to replace the **NULL** values with the respective column attribute value or dummy value(This will work only when all the values of the attribute are same). It might not be the solution that you are looking for,  I just want to show other things that you can do with derived attributes.

See below Image for Reference, I made an assumption that all the values of the column is same and replaced it with column value.

**Example**: 
Col 5 has E, then all the **NULL** values in the column will be replaced with **E**.

This you can achieve this with **Derived Attribute**.

[image]

Sample Derived Attribute definition in the image, 
[image]

Hope it helps.